# Grades from Desire2Learn

Tags: desire2learn

I using the following API to get grades:
For testing, I've hardcoded in the OrgId for a course that exists in our 
Test environment.

```js
uri = userContext.createAuthenticatedUri("/d2l/api/le/1.0/61782/grades/", "GET");
```

However, when I execute this call, I get the data returned below.  It is 
the structure of the Grades, but not the Grades themselves.  How do I 
get the actual grades for all the students, or what parameters am I missing?

```js
[
   {
      "MaxPoints":25.000000000,
      "CanExceedMaxPoints":false,
      "IsBonus":false,
      "ExcludeFromFinalGradeCalculation":false,
      "GradeSchemeId":0,
      "Id":89242,
      "Name":"Quiz #1",
      "ShortName":"",
      "GradeType":"Numeric",
      "CategoryId":93744,
      "Description":{
         "Text":"",
         "Html":""
      }
   },
   {
      "MaxPoints":25.000000000,
      "CanExceedMaxPoints":false,
      "IsBonus":false,
      "ExcludeFromFinalGradeCalculation":false,
      "GradeSchemeId":null,
      "Id":89243,
      "Name":"Quiz #2",
      "ShortName":"",
      "GradeType":"Numeric",
      "CategoryId":93744,
      "Description":{
         "Text":"",
         "Html":""
      }
   },
   {
      "MaxPoints":25.000000000,
      "CanExceedMaxPoints":false,
      "IsBonus":false,
      "ExcludeFromFinalGradeCalculation":false,
      "GradeSchemeId":null,
      "Id":89244,
      "Name":"Quiz #3",
      "ShortName":"",
      "GradeType":"Numeric",
      "CategoryId":93744,
      "Description":{
         "Text":"",
         "Html":""
      }
   },
   {
      "MaxPoints":10.000000000,
      "CanExceedMaxPoints":false,
      "IsBonus":false,
      "ExcludeFromFinalGradeCalculation":false,
      "GradeSchemeId":0,
      "Id":89245,
      "Name":"Assignment 1",
      "ShortName":"",
      "GradeType":"Numeric",
      "CategoryId":0,
      "Description":{
         "Text":"",
         "Html":""
      }
   },
   {
      "MaxPoints":10.000000000,
      "CanExceedMaxPoints":false,
      "IsBonus":false,
      "ExcludeFromFinalGradeCalculation":false,
      "GradeSchemeId":null,
      "Id":89246,
      "Name":"Assignment 2",
      "ShortName":"",
      "GradeType":"Numeric",
      "CategoryId":0,
      "Description":{
         "Text":"",
         "Html":""
      }
   },
   {
      "MaxPoints":40.000000000,
      "CanExceedMaxPoints":false,
      "IsBonus":false,
      "ExcludeFromFinalGradeCalculation":false,
      "GradeSchemeId":null,
      "Id":89247,
      "Name":"Midterm",
      "ShortName":"",
      "GradeType":"Numeric",
      "CategoryId":0,
      "Description":{
         "Text":"",
         "Html":""
      }
   },
   {
      "MaxPoints":106.000000000,
      "CanExceedMaxPoints":false,
      "IsBonus":false,
      "ExcludeFromFinalGradeCalculation":false,
      "GradeSchemeId":null,
      "Id":89248,
      "Name":"Final Exam",
      "ShortName":"",
      "GradeType":"Numeric",
      "CategoryId":0,
      "Description":{
         "Text":"",
         "Html":""
      }
   },
   {
      "Id":94859,
      "Name":"Lec Sect",
      "ShortName":"",
      "GradeType":"Text",
      "CategoryId":0,
      "Description":{
         "Text":"",
         "Html":""
      }
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The call I expect you want is [grades in an org unit by user](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html#get--d2l-api-le-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-%28D2LID-orgUnitId%29-grades-final-values-%28D2LID-userId%29) from the grade values ([actions](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html#id3) and [data structures](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html#grade-values)) area of the docs.

You will need to iterate this call over the classlist of ids.

(A [walk through](http://devs.valence.desire2learn.com/2012/04/18/real-world-application/) and [code snippets](http://devs.valence.desire2learn.com/2012/04/18/real-world-application/#comment-114) are available on the blog)